# Is it possible to activate a profile in maven both with the argument -PmyProfile or with the goal deploy?

Tags: maven

Is it possible to activate a profile in maven both with the argument -PmyProfile or with the maven lifecycle goal deploy ?

I'm trying this but it is not working :

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
       <id>myProfile</id>
       <activation>
       <property>       
          <name>goal</name>
          <value>deploy</value>
       </property>       
        </activation>
    </profiles>
</profile>
```

Comment: Do you really mean the life cycle phase `deploy` or a goal of a particular plugin? Apart from that what kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: the life cycle phase deploy !

Comment: What about the rest of the sentence? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: I want a maven profile that  is automaticly activated when i deploy my application with or when i pass the option -PmyProfile. I don't want to pass this options when i'm deploying (mvn clean deploy -PmyProfile)